# Communication between Web Application and Desktop, what better way?

Tags: java, web-services, web, websocket

Good afternoon everyone!

I have a web application which contains some products need to communicate with a desktop application, when changing inventory, the best way in this case?

Note: Before it was a Desktop System -> Desktop, communication was done by exchanging text files, but now how has the web system is no longer possible, so I would know what the best form of communication between Desktop and Web.

Comment: Why is the text file no longer possible though? Jorge_B's answer is a valid solution, but so is the existing file-exchange idea.

Comment: The reach of the file-exchange version is limited to locations with shared filesystems.  I don't actually know where does OP need to deploy their clients, nor where their server will be; my idea tried to be as broad as possible (actually focused on exposing services from a corporate network to the internet, as was our goal when we faced this same problem in my case)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, we decided to expose our web app functionality as web services, because of:

- The client code is easily generated by your favorite WS library
- The server code is just an annotated POJO and every stub is generated by the same library (say you can choose CXF for both things but there are plenty of options)
- Security and operations people agreeded instantly to our proposal since functionality was exposed to the exterior through the corporative https security (exactly the same as our web application was doing)

The kind of web services you use depends on your requirements: people normally expose their API as a REST api, which is more or less an http CRUD wrapper over your application entities.  You can use standard SOAP web services, which is more of a procedural point of view.

Up to you to decide, I hope this was useful